# How to do a multishot in xna?

Tags: xna, c#, game-design

I am trying to simulate a gun in which shoots multiple bullets at the same time(similar to a spread out shot). I am thinking I have to create another bullet array then do the same as I have below but in a different direction.

Here is what I have so far:

```
foreach (GameObject bullet in bullets) 
    {

            // Find a bullet that isn't alive
            if (!bullet.alive)
            {
                //And set it to alive
                bullet.alive = true;



                if (flip == SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally) //Facing right
                {
                    float armCos = (float)Math.Cos(arm.rotation - MathHelper.PiOver2);
                    float armSin = (float)Math.Sin(arm.rotation - MathHelper.PiOver2);

                    // Set the initial position of our bullets at the end of our gun arm
                    // 42 is obtained by taking the width of the Arm_Gun texture / 2
                    // and subtracting the width of the Bullet texture / 2. ((96/2)=(12/2))
                    bullet.position = new Vector2(
                        arm.position.X + 42 * armCos,
                        arm.position.Y + 42 * armSin);



                    // And give it a velocity of the direction we're aiming.
                    // Increae/decrease speed by changeing 15.0f


                    bullet.Velocity = new Vector2(
                        (float)Math.Cos(arm.rotation - MathHelper.PiOver4 + MathHelper.Pi + MathHelper.PiOver2),
                        (float)Math.Sin(arm.rotation - MathHelper.PiOver4 + MathHelper.Pi + MathHelper.PiOver2)) * 15.0f;



                }


                else //Facing left
                {
                    float armCos = (float)Math.Cos(arm.rotation + MathHelper.PiOver2);
                    float armSin = (float)Math.Sin(arm.rotation + MathHelper.PiOver2);

                    //Set the initial position of our bullet at the end of our gun arm
                    //42 is obtained be taking the width of the Arm_Gun texture / 2
                    //and subtracting the width of the Bullet texture / 2. ((96/2)-(12/2))
                    bullet.position = new Vector2(
                        arm.position.X - 42 * armCos,
                        arm.position.Y - 42 * armSin);

                    //And give it a velocity of the direction we're aiming.
                    //Increase/decrease speed by changing 15.0f
                    bullet.Velocity = new Vector2(
                       -armCos,
                       -armSin) * 15.0f;
                }

                return;
            }// End if

    }// End foreach
```

Comment: Please explain why this doesn't do what you want and what you'd like to do instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using some sort of pre-created bullet pool and every time the player shoots you call the above method? I would do the following.

1. Create a bullet creation method - Instead of hard coding the logic of setting the velocity and position you can encapsulate this in a method:

   ```
   public Bullet createBullet(Vector2 position, Vector2 velocity)
   {
       Bullet b = getUnusedBullet();
       b.velocity = velocity;
       b.position = position;
       b.alive = true;
       return b;
   }
   ```
2. Have this method in a singleton service that can be accessed by your gun object.

   ```
   public class BulletService
   {
       private static BulletService instance;

       private BulletService() { }

       public static BulletService getBulletService() 
       {
           if(instance == null)
           {
               instance = new BulletService();
           }
           return instance;
       }

       // Implementation logic...
   }
   ```
3. Have your bullet pool inside this singleton service, the service should also handle stuff like updating the bullets during the update loop, managing the bullet pool e.t.c.
4. Your gun object can then call call it as follows:

   ```
       private void shoot()
       {
           BulletService bulletService = BulletService.getBulletService();
           bulletService.shoot(position, angle);
           bulletService.shoot(position, angle);
           bulletService.shoot(position, angle);
           //e.t.c.
       }
   ```

The above is one way to solve the problem, there are many many other ways but in general you should break up the code and make things reusable if it makes sense.

Your bullet pool logic is horribly inefficient as well, you shouldn't loop through every bullet everytime you need to find a new one that you can use. There are ways to do pools with all operations being constant time. This is a very simple to understand implementation: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ObjectPool.aspx There are better ones that don't affect the GC at all but the above one should suffice.